# Problems using localStorage with Gatsby & Zustand-persist?

Tags: local-storage, gatsby, zustand

I am using Zustand in my Gatsby app to manage global state, one of my slices syncs with local storage using `zustand-persist`.
I didnt catch what caused Gatsby to start failing (maybe updated dependency?) but now i get the following error when running `gatsby build`:
`WebpackError: ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined`

Here is my code:

```
import create from 'zustand'
import { configurePersist } from 'zustand-persist';

const { persist, purge } = configurePersist({
  storage: localStorage
})
```

I tried:

```
import { create } from 'zustand'
import { configurePersist } from 'zustand-persist';

const isBrowser = typeof window !== "undefined";

const { persist, purge } = configurePersist({
  storage: isBrowser ? window?.localStorage : null, // use `AsyncStorage` in react native
  // rootKey: 'root', // optional, default value is `root`
})
```

But am getting this error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getItem')`

Do I need to actually mock these methods out so it doesnt break the build?
Is there no gatsby-specific package to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this so that the function is still available and wont error but it returns null.

```
const isBrowser = typeof window !== "undefined";
const localStorage = isBrowser ? window.localStorage : {
  getItem: () => null,
}

const { persist, purge } = configurePersist({
  storage: localStorage,
});
```